# Where is the board column information stored for an Azure DevOps task?

Tags: azure-boards

When configuring Azure DevOps boards columns, you can tell what state is associated with what column. Also, multiple columns can have the same state defined.

How does Azure knows which column to use for the card? Where is this information stored?

Answer (score 0):

It's all stored in the Work Item Template. Templates have section headings for `FIELDS`, `WORKFLOW` and `FORM`. The swimlanes/columns are defined in the `WORKFLOW` section of the work item template, specifically the `STATE` element.